# vscode.WorkSpaceEdit: does it work on files that are currently not opened in the editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

From the documentation it is unclear to me if WorkspaceEdits do only affect currently opened files or if vscode is intelligent enough to change also files that are currently closed.

Answer (score 0):

A WorkspaceEdit is applied to a workspace, defined as "A representation of the folder that has been opened" as described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_workspace).

The workspace is inherently the open folder in the explorer view, but the files affected by the workspaceEdit do not have to be open in the editor view for it take effect.

Comment: The link does not work. From your explanation I'm still not sure. What confuses me is: "but the files affected by the workspaceEdit do not have to be open in the editor view".
That means: it will affect also not-opened files as long as they are in the workspace (and the workspace is shown in the explorer).

Comment: Apologies, fixed the link! Yep correct, the edits are workspace wide.

Comment: I tested this but it works only partly. I.e. I created a WorkSpaceEdit that does a rename and used it on a file in the workspace that was not opened.
Now the file is changed that is correct, but the file is also opened in the editor automatically and stays there unsaved.
Is there any way I can tell the WorkSpaceEdit just to do the rename without opening in the editor?

Comment: I don't know of a way to stop workspaceEdit from opening the files. You could follow it with workspace.saveAll() and workspace.updateWorkspaceFolders() to remove the opened files that you want to close.